# Applying log on a generating function

Tags: logarithms, generating-functions

I am reading the Book SymmetricFunctions and Hall Polynomials by MacDonald and now reached the chapter "Power Sums" (Starting on Page 23). There we want to proof
$[P(t)=H'(t)/H(t)]$
In the last step of the proof we get

$P(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}log(H(t)),$ where $H(t)$ is a generating function.
What does $log$ of a generating function mean??? Is this the same as applying $log$ on a "normal" power series?

Comment: It is applying the $\log$ to a function

Comment: But i thought there would be a difference between a function and a generating function because we have formal variables and formal power series. Does our log have to be a formal log? and if yes, how can i formalise this?

Comment: yes, it is formal $\log$ and you can formalize it as a formal power series